# Change image on battery level Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, battery, batterylevel

my application show the battery level.. I have three batteries images; One gree, one yellow and another one red. I want place in a imageview these images when battery level change.. For example: when the battery is 100% there will be the green battery, when 50% the yellow and 20% red. How can i do it? For now i have a static image in a listview simply like this:

```
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/BatteryInfoimage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="image"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/battery"
            />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the battery level using [BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html). see the doc [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#CurrentLevel)

```
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

Now from the code depending of the batterPct set the specific image

And to Monitor the change use the following

Declare a BroadCastReceiver

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Within the associated BroadcastReceiver implementation, you can extract the current charging state and method as described in the previous step.

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                            status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah but how can insert the image and change it when the batteryPct reach that levels? (100%, 50% and 20%)? All by java i think.

Comment: Thanks, and to insert an image?

Comment: simply set the backgournd.. setBackGroundResource

Comment: but, have i to do something like: `if (level<100) ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.BatteryInfoimage );
  i.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery);`?